# Blank Chart When Parsing Data From Async Function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, dom-events, angular-promise

I have a problem when I want to parse the data, which get from http call, and parsing it to chart data that located ngoninit. When page reload, the chart is show blank data. Can you help me to solve this problem? I am using Chartist.js and Angular 4.

The html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <lbd-chart 
                  [title]="'Email Statistics'"
                  [subtitle]="'Last Campaign Performance'"
                  [chartClass]="'ct-perfect-fourth'"
                  [chartType]="emailChartType"
                  [chartData]="emailChartData"
                  [legendItems]="emailChartLegendItems"
                  [withHr]="true"
                  [footerIconClass]="'fa fa-clock-o'"
                  [footerText]="'Campaign sent 2 days ago'">
                </lbd-chart>
            </div>
```

The ngOnInit:

```
 async ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
    const data1 = await this.serviceDashboard.getAllGeografika().toPromise();
    const data2 = await this.serviceDashboard.getAllHistorika().toPromise();
    const data3 = await this.serviceDashboard.getAllKeramologika().toPromise();


    this.data1 = data1.length;
    this.data2 = data2.length;
    this.data3 = data3.length;

    this.emailChartType = ChartType.Pie;
    this.emailChartData = {

      series: [this.data1, this.data2, this.data3]
    };

    this.emailChartLegendItems = [
      { title: 'Open', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-info' },
      { title: 'Bounce', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-danger' },
      { title: 'Unsubscribe', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-warning' }
    ];
}
```

Comment: If I'm correct you're setting your ``emailChartData`` with array of numbers. Is that really what you want?

Comment: *which get from http call* ... Can you `console.log()` the result and include in your question?

Comment: yes, i want to print emailChartData result in html

Answer (score 0):

1) I would prefer rxjs over async/await paradigma.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
    const data1$ = this.serviceDashboard.getAllGeografika();
    const data2$ = this.serviceDashboard.getAllHistorika();
    const data3$ = this.serviceDashboard.getAllKeramologika();

    this.chartContext$ = combineLatest([data1$, data2$, data3$])
                        .pipe(
                           map(([d1, d2, d3]) => {
                               return {
                                 emailChartType: ChartType.Pie,
                                 emailChartData: [d1, d2, d3],
                                 emailChartLegendItems = [
                     { title: 'Open', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-info' },
                     { title: 'Bounce', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-danger' },
                     { title: 'Unsubscribe', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-warning' }
                                 ]
                               }
                             }
                           )
                        )
}

// And template

<div class="col-md-4">
  <lbd-chart 
     *ngIf="chartContext$ | async as chart"
     [title]="'Email Statistics'"
     [subtitle]="'Last Campaign Performance'"
     [chartClass]="'ct-perfect-fourth'"
     [chartType]="chart.emailChartType"
     [chartData]="chart.emailChartData"
     [legendItems]="chart.emailChartLegendItems"
     [withHr]="true"
     [footerIconClass]="'fa fa-clock-o'"
     [footerText]="'Campaign sent 2 days ago'">
   </lbd-chart>
</div>
```

2) Anyway 1) maybe won´t help you. Chartist.js and Angular 4? You should maybe consider better chart library and current (9) version of Angular. D3.js has never failed anyone (but you would have to create your own chart components :-))

3) Have you tried just put dummy fake data in your chart without querying the API and see if it works?

Comment: Option 1 didn't work. I want to print just the length of the data, so it can be directly show in pie chart. Do you have any option ?

Comment: Just print it in the template in the first place...

<div>{{data | json}}</div> 
// in my example it would be {{chartContext$ | async | json}}

Comment: Are you sure that the data flows to your template correctly? That they are really there?